# I am trying to create a speech to text input in html that will work in Internet Explorer (Windows 10 a.k.a Edge), is there a way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like a simple input text bar that looks like:

[this](http://prntscr.com/atcsxg)

However, I would like there to be a way that someone can speak their text into their microphone, is there a way for it to work in Microsoft Edge?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edge does not support the Speech Recognition API](http://caniuse.com/#search=speech), so this is not possible.

Only Chrome and Opera have it available at this moment.